# Are upvotes on comments lost, if a question is removed?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

E.g I got 5 upvotes on a comment I left on a question that was removed, does this mean I lost the votes?

Comment: Why do you care? It's just a comment.

Comment: Why not? I would like to know to things work on this site.

Comment: +1 to Harry's comment, thought this was what MSO was for...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I assume you are asking if the comment votes still count toward the Pundit badge. You did not lose those comment votes in terms of your badge progress.

In other words:
**Comments on deleted posts count toward the Pundit badge.**

Comment: I thought that myself, sure they won't count as the question has been removed. Hence the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I personally got the badge with 7 qualified comments that I could see so either the system is messed up or deleted posts count.

Comment: @Anonymous: I guess that since you cannot vote on comments, they reached the threshold *before* the post was deleted and thus could still count.

Comment: I guess it makes some sense. It does seem the system may be flawed.

Comment: so is it possible to somehow see the real Pundit progress in contrast to this method https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340155/3995261 ? I know it's kinda silly question since this doesn't means much anyway, but out of curiosity...

Comment: @YakovL If SEDE doesn’t show deleted comments, there is no way for <10k rep users to see the real progress.

Comment: @Anonymous: I have >10k and how can I see the "real" progress which includes deleted comments?

Comment: @ArunVinoth There's no easy way. I was talking about how 10k users can see deleted posts. You still need to know which posts you left comments on. The feature to see real progress is [status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34440/261238).