# How did I get Pundit badge?

Tags: discussion, bug, badges

I have noticed today that I was awarded this badge.  When I see its description, it says

```
Leave 10 comments with score of 5 or more.
```

I was interested to see which 10 comments attracted the score.  I search a number of posts on meta and found [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/49864/my-comments-ordered-by-score-pundit-badge-progress), [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73986/new-pundit-progress) and [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/190364/my-comments-ordered-by-score-pundit-badge-progress#resultSets) link, which are supposed to retrieve the comments with their score.

When I entered my user id `2169261`, I was surprised to see that there are, in fact, only 5 comments which has more than score of 5.

Is it a bug? Or Are these queries missing something?

It was awarded 22 hours ago and I believe it has nothing to do with cache!! In order to rule this out, I opened a few questions from the SEDE output and noticed that the score on comment matches with SEDE output.

I hope it doesn't include any comments on posts that were deleted!!

Comment: SEDE is refreshed once in a week.

Comment: @BhargavRao - I went into a number of questions that were retrieved from those queries and the actual score of comments on the posts match with what we see in the SEDE output.

Comment: You have posted two popular comments this week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962714/sql-server-invalid-column-name-when-using-alias-name#comment67205216_39962714 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965573/updating-a-column-from-one-row-to-the-other#comment67210900_39965573 which account for two of your missing comments.

Comment: @Kendra - Yes, I have just seen them! Still, there are a few unaccounted.  Need to look for more :)

Comment: @yellowantphil - I marked only three and out of three 2 were found

Comment: @techspider I just got this badge awarded while according to SEDE I only have 2 "5+" comments (and 1 more that is not yet in SEDE). [**It appears that deleted comments also count towards your Pundit badge**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268724/are-upvotes-on-comments-lost-if-a-question-is-removed/268725#268725).

Comment: Duplicate of [Why did I get the Pundit badge?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/163502)