# How to see your progression on the Pundit badge?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

Since I [can not select the Pundit badge in the *"Next badge list"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291595/why-isnt-the-pundit-badge-displayed-on-the-next-badge-list), how can I **know my progression** on the [*Pundit*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit) badge?

> **Pundit:** Leave 10 comments with score of 5 or more.

---

Update: As [deleted comments count for the badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268724/are-upvotes-on-comments-lost-if-a-question-is-removed/268725#268725), it seems a bit hard even with a SEDE query (as suggest by [*@Glorfindel*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340155/4927984)) to know the progression.

Comment: That interface is only meant for tag badges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't the Pundit Badge displayed on the Next Badge list?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291595/why-isnt-the-pundit-badge-displayed-on-the-next-badge-list)

Comment: As your link may answer of part of my question, it does not answer the main part that is **how can I know my progression**. Your link only explain **why** it is not in the next badge list. Furthermore, it has not been answered.

Answer (score 16):

As Cerbrus notes, you're looking at the wrong badge tracker. You'll need the one in the block of your profile showing the number of badges. Still, Pundit is not available there.

One way to do this would be a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query. [This one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/591137/progress-towards-commentator-pundit) tells me you only have one +5 comment so far.

Note that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Glorfindel. Another point: Does comments on Meta counts for this badge?

Comment: @Mistalis: sort of. Meta is its own site; I do have a [Pundit badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/56/pundit?userid=4751173) here, but not on the main site.

Comment: Your query will not exactly show progression as [deleted comments still counts in Pundit progression](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268724/are-upvotes-on-comments-lost-if-a-question-is-removed/268725#268725), but won't be shown on your SEDE query.