# How to track progress on badges that aren't shown as available

Tags: support, badges

Often while using SO, I feel like tracking a certain badge that I want to get. For tracking badges, I can, of course, go to my profile page and then click on the small gear icon beside the `Next badge` text. However, I can only track my progress on certain badges that are shown under the `Available` tab. Examples of badges that aren't shown under the `Available` tab are the `Guru` or the `Great Question` badge. It isn't that unavailable badges aren't awarded, because I was awarded the `Tenacious` badge which doesn't show up under `Available`. How can I track my progress on badges that aren't shown under `Available`?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263610/why-arent-all-the-badges-shown-on-the-track-menu

Comment: What badges specifically? They (mostly) have different triggers.

Comment: @Laurel I want to track quite a few badges, like, `Favorite Question` & `Pundit`.

Comment: You can't track "Favorite Question" anymore. Also, the latter request is a duplicate of [How to see your progression on the Pundit badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340154/6083675)

Comment: Related: *[What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I track my progress on badges that aren't shown under Available?

The cross-site duplicate on Meta.SE explains that these badges would be too resource-intensive to track. I want to offer a separate perspective that happens to tie into that.

You can't, because *the concept of "progress" does not make sense for those badges*. That's **why** they aren't "Available".

The "Available" badges are the ones that are awarded when you successfully take some action N times (where N could be 1), and which are awarded only once each (because they already reflect the number of times you've done something)

On the other hand, a badge like "Great Question" is awarded multiple times (every time you ask a question that meets the criteria), and is awarded according to the actions of others (when your question reaches a score of 100). It doesn't make sense to track "progress towards" this result: whichever of your questions currently has the highest score could be overtaken by a different question; you aren't continually doing things to make the question get a higher score; and having reached this mark, you aren't "done" with the "achievement".

This is also related to why it would be computationally expensive to try to "track" these achievements. Say for example we wanted the UI to show "26/100" for the "Great Question" achievement as soon as you got another upvote on the "Good Question" you just got. Then it would have to check *all of your questions, every time*. Presumably, the database doesn't have the indices required to make this sort of thing performant. Comparatively, however, it's easy to track something like "Ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a positive question record", because the database (the real one, not just what's exposed on SEDE) can increment a counter associated with your user data as part of the nightly update job if you had a well-received question that day.