# "Track the next badge" shows tag badges instead of regular ones

Tags: bug, badges, badge-progress

**Update**: this is *definitely* not a duplicate of the post [How to track progress on badges that aren't shown as available](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426781/14015737). This post deals with something completely different. I edited the description and tried to make this even more clear.

---

I was on my cellphone (Android 13 with Chrome 117.0.5938.153) when I earned a badge and subsequently attempted to set tracking of the next badge on my profile page by selecting <kbd>Track the next one</kbd>:

[image]

However, the dialog that opened incorrectly offered selecting the wrong category of badges.  The list to choose from was populated with new **tag badges** to track instead of **regular ones**:

[image]

When selecting one of the badges, the currently tracked *tag badge* was indeed updated, and after closing the dialog by clicking the <kbd>x</kbd> button in the top right corner, the option to select a new *regular* badge (unsurprisingly) is still there:

[image]

I assume this is a bug.

Since I already proceeded to select a badge on my cellphone, I cannot test if this behavior was specific to the mobile version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no, that is an entirely different topic, and I believe that should be clear from the content of my post? I am not talking about tracking badges that aren't shown as available, but instead that the track dialog erroneously offers the wrong category of badges (tag badges instead of regular ones). To be frank, I am a bit startled that this could have been misinterpreted by so many people who read the post, judging from the number of upvotes to your comment. Could you please suggest which part of my post should be edited to avoid this apparent confusion? Thank you.